# Performance difference between 'variable == true' vs 'true == variable'

Tags: c#, performance

> This needs to be closed / deleted because the difference wasn't their
>   it was my own fault. But i don't want to delete my own question
>   because i can get blocked. so if there is a moderator that can do this
>   for me..

I was hoping that someone can tell me what the performance difference is between

`variable == true` vs `true == variable`
After some tests i se that `true == variable` is almost twice as slow as `variable == true` maybe it totally irrelevant but i was just wondering.

but after some runs i see the following outcome:

Performance test for `'variableTrue == true' vs 'true == variableTrue'`

```
Performance for 'variableTrue == true'
Average: 0.333442949999999 ms
Min: 0.2784 ms
Max: 7.6198 ms

Performance for 'variableTrue == false'
Average: 0.330602419999998 ms
Min: 0.2784 ms
Max: 10.2835 ms

Performance for 'true == variableTrue'
Average: 0.668567990000006 ms
Min: 0.5568 ms
Max: 7.9245 ms

Performance for 'false == variableTrue'
Average: 0.660314390000008 ms
Min: 0.5568 ms
Max: 10.5792 ms
```

Performance test for `'variableFalse == false' vs 'false == variableFalse'`

```
Performance for 'variableFalse == true'
Average: 0.31614 ms
Min: 0.295 ms
Max: 0.4047 ms

Performance for 'variableFalse == false'
Average: 0.29688 ms
Min: 0.2947 ms
Max: 0.3082 ms

Performance for 'true == variableFalse'
Average: 0.74112 ms
Min: 0.5901 ms
Max: 1.9459 ms

Performance for 'false == variableFalse'
Average: 0.62093 ms
Min: 0.5895 ms
Max: 0.781 ms

Press any key to continue
```

The code i tested it with can be found here
['variable == true' vs 'true == variable'](https://github.com/jordyvaneijk/-true-variable-vs-variable-true-)

Comment: I hope you are compiling in release mode, and executing without the debugger attached (directly from command line or shift-F5 in visual studio). Microbenchmarking is *very* complex.

Comment: Ah and it is sanDbox, not sanbbox

Comment: What about just `variable` instead of comparing it to `true` or `!variable` instead of comparing to `false`?  That would be my personal preference when dealing with a `bool`.

Comment: Use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) (start without attached debugger, release, from console)

Comment: @xanatos this was without debugging just started the the exe itself

Comment: There is nothing wrong with deleting your own question ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference. Here is why:

Code:

```
public class C {
    private bool value = false;

    public void M() {
        if(value == true)
        {

        }

        if(true == value)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

What is generated:

```
// Fields
.field private bool 'value'

// Methods
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void M () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 26 (0x1a)
    .maxstack 1
    .locals init (
        [0] bool, // first bool variable
        [1] bool  // second bool variable
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0               // load first bool
    IL_0002: ldfld bool C::'value' // load value
    IL_0007: stloc.0               // store field in first bool
    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_0008: ldloc.0               // load first bool
    IL_0009: brfalse.s IL_000d     // branch if false

    IL_000b: nop                   // debug garbage
    IL_000c: nop                   // debug garbage

    IL_000d: ldarg.0               // load first bool
    IL_000e: ldfld bool C::'value' // load value
    IL_0013: stloc.1               // store value in second bool
    // sequence point: hidden
    IL_0014: ldloc.1               // load second bool
    IL_0015: brfalse.s IL_0019     // branch if false

    IL_0017: nop
    IL_0018: nop

    IL_0019: ret
} // end of method C::M
```

Compiled in Debug mode, but it doesn't matter. The point is, both `if` statements are exactly the same. Release version is much "nicer":

```
.field private static bool 'value'

.method private hidebysig static void 
Main(
  string[] args
) cil managed 
{
.entrypoint
.maxstack 8

// [18 13 - 18 31]
IL_0000: ldsfld       bool ConsoleA.Program::'value' // Load value
IL_0005: brfalse.s    IL_000d                        // Branch if false

// USED ONLY SO COMPILER WONT COMPLETELY REMOVE IF STATEMENTS
// [20 17 - 20 36]
IL_0007: ldnull       
IL_0008: call         void [mscorlib]System.GC::KeepAlive(object)

// [23 13 - 23 31]
IL_000d: ldsfld       bool ConsoleA.Program::'value'  // Load value
IL_0012: brfalse.s    IL_001a                         // Branch if false

// USED ONLY SO COMPILER WONT COMPLETELY REMOVE IF STATEMENTS
// [25 17 - 25 36]
IL_0014: ldnull       
IL_0015: call         void [mscorlib]System.GC::KeepAlive(object)

// [27 9 - 27 10]
IL_001a: ret          

} // end of method Program::Main
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains a typo, on [line 146](https://github.com/jordyvaneijk/-true-variable-vs-variable-true-/blob/master/PerformanceSanbbox/Program.cs#L146), the same occurs in line [160](https://github.com/jordyvaneijk/-true-variable-vs-variable-true-/blob/master/PerformanceSanbbox/Program.cs#L160).

You don't use the correct stopwatch. Be careful with copy/pasting.

Using the correct one and you'll get the almost exact same execution times as tend to prove FCin's answer.

See result:

[image]

Comment: thank for pointing this out to me...

Comment: @JordyvanEijk I would do [something like this](https://pastebin.com/Fe8TA9HK)